# How to copy a python bytearray buffer?

Tags: python, arrays

I have two network buffers defined as:

```
buffer1 = bytearray(4096)
buffer2 = bytearray(4096)
```

Which is the fastest way to move the content from `buffer2` to `buffer1` without allocating extra memory?

The naive way would be to do:

```
for i in xrange(4096):
    buffer1[i] = buffer2[i]
```

Apparently if I do `buffer1[:]=buffer2[:]` python moves the content, but I'm not 100% sure of it because if I do:

```
a = bytearray([0,0,0])
b = bytearray([1,1])
a[:]=b[:]
```

then `len(a)=2`. What happens with the missing byte? Can anyone explain how this works or how to move data between buffers?

Thanks.

Comment: I think what you are doing in your first code is "move the content from buffer2 to buffer1", not the opposite.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On my computer, the following

```
buffer1[:] = buffer2
```

copies a 4KB buffer in under 400 nanoseconds. In other words, you can do 2.5 million such copies per second.

Is this fast enough for your needs?

**edit:** If `buffer2` is shorter than `buffer1`, and you want to copy its contents at a particular position in `buffer1` *without changing the rest of the target buffer*, you can use the following:

```
buffer1[pos:pos+len(buffer2)] = buffer2
```

Similarly, you can use slicing on the right-hand side to only copy a portion of `buffer2`.

Comment: What happens then in the case where "a=bytearray([0,0,0]);b=bytearray([1,1]);a[:]=b;" Where does the missing byte goes?

Comment: @Lluis: Well, you're making a copy of a buffer that contains two bytes. The result therefore also contains two bytes.

Comment: That is my problem. I don't want to make a copy of buffer2 but move its contents to buffer1.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I'll use the buffer1[:] = buffer2 option.

Comment: Another followup question: What if I want to copy part of `buffer2` into `buffer1`, without copying `buffer2`? Say both buffers are 10 bytes long, and I want to copy the first 5 bytes of one into the other?

Comment: Ah apparently you do that with `memoryview`: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews